# Tabs > fragments with different layout + actions

Tags: java, android, tabs

I'm new to android studio / java language.
 
I need to set up a pretty straightforward app, but the information I find doesn't let me solve the problem.
Can any of you help :)?

I want to make an app with 3 tabs

- **(first tab)** user enters a decimal number, and after click of a button the result shows a value calculated with the means of a formula
- **(second tab)** same as first tab but with values and formulas
- **(third tab)** information of each formula

I've implemented a (for this use, simplified) code for the first tab.

> I know how to code all the three tabs separately, but **I don't know how
>   to merge them together in one app with 3 tabs.**

I started with the `tabs-template` given in android studio, but it demands that every `tablayout` is the same. I've seen a lot of answers how to have different layouts for each tab, but how do I code the different tabs (e.g. `setonclicklistener`).

Second problem is that every solution uses android and I have `androidx`, so the imports won't take. And in dependencies I don't find design `V7` or anything of that sort.

---

**Mainactivity.java:**

```
package com.example.soloapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.0");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button calcButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcButton);
        calcButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                EditText editNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editNum);
                TextView resultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);

                double cysC = Double.parseDouble(editNum.getText().toString());
                double tempResult = Math.pow(cysC,-0.931);
                double resultLong = 70.69 * tempResult;
                String result = numberFormat.format(resultLong);
                resultTextView.setText(result);

            }


        });

    }
}
```

---

**activy_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editNum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/resultTextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="168dp"
        android:text="Result"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/calcButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calcButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
        android:text="CALCULATE"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: ```Can you help me --> Thanks in advance.

If you don't know the answer --> have a great day :)``` this is not relevant when you ask for help

Comment: Being polite and friendly is always relevant, **especially** when asking for help ;) You should try it, makes a difference! Also for you a great day !

Answer (score 1):

I'll add what you need to learn in order to create what you told.

1. You need to use `ViewPager` in Android to create swipeable tabs. (If you know WhatsApp, those swipeable three tabs are `ViewPager`).

   You can learn more about `ViewPager` [here](https://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/viewpager).
2. For using `ViewPagers`, you need to learn what `Fragments` are, `Fragments` in Android are like small activities(but not activities). You embed these `Fragments` inside your `Activities`, so you need to put these `Fragments` inside the `Activity` that contains your `ViewPager`.

You can learn about Fragments [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm).

Although, the first `ViewPager` link will be sufficient for you to learn everything that you need to learn about creating Swipeable Tabs.

About the **second problem** that you mentioned.

According to [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate),

> Androidx only maps the original support library API packages into the
> androidx namespace.

Basically, they just renamed the package name so that it'd be easy for them to support the updates to libraries.

You can easily find the corresponding androidx package from here.

[Migrating to Androidx.](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)